# Passing data from android activity to broadcast receiver on device boot up

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

I always get bundle value `null` when I pass data from activity to broadcast receiver.
My receiver will start on boot up.

This is the code in my activity class

```
Intent intent= new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED");
intent.putExtra("test", "test");    
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This is the code in my receiver class:

```
String testValue = intent.getStringExtra("test");
```

Comment: how are you sending data from activity to receiver as receiver will trigger on bootup not activity

Comment: I am sending data from activity to receiver so is that wrong?

Comment: you can't send data like this as activity will not be running when your phone boot up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in activity will never be called upon booting up. System invokes onReceive() with its own intent. You can check this by putting some logs in activity code - this log will not be printed in logcat.